# Observable, am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, typescript, geolocation, angular, rxjs

I have this service:

```
 getPosition(): Observable<Object> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((pos: Position) => {
            observer.next(pos);
            observer.complete();
        }),
        () => {
            console.log('Position is not available');
        },
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        };
    });
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
this.getLocationService.getPosition().subscribe((pos: Position) => {
        self._latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
        self._longitude = pos.coords.longitude; }
```

But unfortunately it does not work. I assumed every time position changes, the lat and long would change. But it does not work.

Comment: watchPosition  should get the new position and update the observable

Answer (score 7):

One issue here is related to Observable contract

> ### [The Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)
>
> “The Observable Contract,” which you may see referenced in various places in source documentation and in the pages on this site,
>   is an attempt at a formal definition of an Observable, based
>   originally on the 2010 document Rx Design Guidelines from Microsoft
>   that described its Rx.NET implementation of ReactiveX.
>        This page summarizes The Observable Contract.
>
> #### Notifications
>
> ```
> An Observable communicates with its observers with the following notifications:
> ```
>
> - OnNext
>         conveys an item that is emitted by the Observable to the observer
> - **OnCompleted**
>         indicates that the Observable has completed successfully and
>          **that it will be emitting no further items**
> - ...

So, if you want to continue to fire events, you should not call completed

```
 getPosition(): Observable<Object> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((pos: Position) => {
            observer.next(pos);
            // simply call next again, but not complete
            // until position is completed
            //observer.complete();
        }),
        ...
```

Comment: I assume that every time position changes, the observer.next(pos) will get called with new position got from the geolocation.watchPosition . Am I wrong here ?

Comment: It would be true, unless you stop after first watch trigger, by calling complete... that will (by contract) mean, there are no other NEXT expected.. stop observing... does it help a it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a misplaced comma, moreover you should stop the watcher on unsubscribe and forward the error to the observer.

```
public $getDeviceLocation():Observable<Position> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {

        const onSuccess:PositionCallback = (pos:Position) => {
            observer.next(pos);
        };

        const onError:PositionErrorCallback = (error) => {
            observer.error(error);
        };

        const options:PositionOptions = this.locationOptions();

        const watcher:number = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        return () => {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watcher);
        };
    });
}
```